# Python detects Vanity URL discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py, vanity-url

I am making a Serverinfo command on my bot. So i want add the server info command show the guild's vanity too! But I read the whole discord documentation but can't find how can i make the bot detect the vanity url and sends it. Then I tried to test by making that command as a single command. Here is my code:

```
@bot.command()
async def vanity(ctx):
  vanity = str(ctx.guild.vanity_url)
  await ctx.send(vanity)
```

The bot doesn't response with the code. A help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to get the vanity url:

```
vanity = (await ctx.guild.vanity_invite()).url
```

Documentation reference: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.vanity_invite

Comment: Hey, Guess its now giving me error..:here is the traceback:

`main.py:1132: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Guild.vanity_invite' was never awaited
  vanity = (await ctx.guild.vanity_invite().url)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback`

Help me out please.

Comment: ok sorry I put a bracket in the wrong place - code should be working now :)

Comment: Yo, Really appreciate your help man! It worked